# With Pandas, how do I use to_sql to insert a cell with lists into a Postgresql database?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I'm stuck on how to insert a column that contains lists into a Postgresql database. I know it is theoretically possible, because there are datatypes like BIGINT[] that exist, whereas it doesn't exist with other SQL variants.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import json
import pandas as pd
import pymysql.cursors

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
                            
mock_data = {}
mock_data['a'] = 'HELLO'
mock_data['b'] = {
    'c' : {
        'd' : True,
# NOTE: If you replace this with 'e' : '', instead of the list, it works fine.
        'e' : []
    },
    'f' : 'TESTING'
}

df = pd.json_normalize(mock_data)

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:ABCDEFG@localhost:5432/testing")
con = engine.connect()

table_name = 'testing-db'

try:
    frame = df.to_sql(con=con, name=table_name, index=False, if_exists='replace')
    display(frame)
except ValueError as vx:
    print(vx)
except Exception as ex:   
    print(ex)
else:
    print("Table %s created successfully."%table_name);   
finally:
    connection.close()
```

The code above fails, due to 'e' : []. Python/Pandas doesn't report a failure, but I can't see the table being updated in Postgres. However, if you changed the list to an empty string, like this: 'e' : ''
The postgres database is updated. I can't figure out how to insert a list into a Postgres database with Pandas. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I had to use the `dtypes` field to make it work. So here's the changes I had to make:

```
dtypes = {
    'a' : types.TEXT(),
    'b.c.d' : types.BOOLEAN(),
    'b.c.e' : types.ARRAY(types.BIGINT()),
    'b.f' : types.TEXT() 
}
...
    frame = df.to_sql(con=con, 
                      name=table_name, 
                      index=False, 
                      dtype=dtypes,
                      if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert list in a SQL Database Cell as it breaks the normalization parameters.

What you can do instead is:

1. Convert your list to a json string object (or XML)
2. Create a new table that has the elements in individual cells and refers to original table.

For example: If you have a list field for which the length is fixed

```
list_field = [Element_A, Element_B, Element_C]
```

You can create another table list_data that has 4 columns (1 primary and 3 columns). Store your list data here and use this to refer your original table. This gives you a far more efficient handle on the data values and is the traditional way of doing so.

However, if you have variable length list_data, it is far more efficient to just dump it in a json and store it as a json or string object. But remember doing so will mean that you will have to pre-process the response on each fetch to get the data you want.