# Polars + Psycopg2: write column of lists to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, python-polars

I'm trying to write a table that has a column of lists. When writing, I was initially getting an error due to psycopg2 not being able to transform the `np.array` datatype to a postgre type.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564755/programmingerror-psycopg2-programmingerror-cant-adapt-type-numpy-ndarray) I learned of adapters and tried both the `AsIs` and the `QuotedString` ones, trying to imitate the string one would use in SQL.

Let's see a MWE: in SQL, the following works

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_arrays (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    foo REAL [],
    bar VARCHAR (24)
);

INSERT INTO test_arrays (foo, bar)
VALUES('{1.0, 4.0}', 'baz');

INSERT INTO test_arrays (foo, bar)
VALUES('{2.0, 42.0}', 'qux');
```

my attempt in Python to write the same table, but the `foo` column is of type text:

```py
import polars as pl


def register_psycopg_adapters():
    import numpy as np
    from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, QuotedString

    def addapt_numpy_array(numpy_array):

        # should return e.g. '{1.0, 4.0}'
        return QuotedString("{" + ", ".join(map(str, numpy_array)) + "}")

    register_adapter(np.ndarray, addapt_numpy_array)


def test_writing_array_to_postgres():
    conn = "..." # the connection string
    register_psycopg_adapters()

    df = pl.DataFrame(
        dict(
            foo=[[1.0, 42.0], [4.0, 7.0]],
            bar=["baz", "qux"],
        )
    )

    df.write_database("test_arrays", conn, if_exists="replace")
```

I'd like to know how to write the foo column as an ARRAY type.

Comment: With your new approach what isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error, it simply writes the array to the database as a Text type instead of Array type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polars `write_database` uses as its default a conversion of your df to pandas and then the use of pandas to_sql method.

It seems you're already, at least implicitly, detecting this because you're looking at having `np.array`s which is only the case because of the conversion to pandas.

Anyway, it seems the issue is that you need to make your `dtypes` explicit like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477081/with-pandas-how-do-i-use-to-sql-to-insert-a-cell-with-lists-into-a-postgresql-d) question.

`write_database` doesn't forward that parameter so you'll have copy paste what polars is doing so that you can have access to the dtypes.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine_sa = create_engine(connection)
df.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True).to_sql(
    name="test_arrays",
    con=engine_sa,
    if_exists="replace",
    index=False,
    dtypes={
        'foo': types.ARRAY(types.REAL()), # or maybe DOUBLE depending on use case
        'bar': types.TEXT()
    }
)
```

As for the `types`, it looks like that should be imported from [sqlalchemy](https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/core/type_basics.html)

The other, non-default, alternative for `write_database` is to use adbc but [it doesn't support the ARRAY type](https://arrow.apache.org/adbc/0.1.0/driver/cpp/postgresql.html) as of now so it won't help you in this case.

Comment: the type DOUBLE should be REAL and you missed a comma in the dict. Other than that, it worked, thanks

Comment: @Adrian awesome, glad it works, I made those tweaks for the next person.